# How can I incorporate error handling into this powershell code?

Tags: powershell, winforms, error-handling

I have a script that creates a GUI via windows forms with powershell. The form allows the user to select a file from their computer, paste a list of hostnames into a text box, and click a button to transfer the selected file to the list of computers that were input into the text box.

The things mentioned above work, but when it runs into errors, it crashes. I need to incorporate error handling but cant seem to figure it out.

When I try to incorporate my own way of error handling, some of the functions of others are lost and I'm not sure why. I am trying to achieve the following logic for error handling:

1. When there is no file selected AND a computer(s) in the text box, display "Please select a file to transfer" dialog box. (Currently in the script, but loses function when I try to incorporate other error handling)
2. When there is a file selected AND no computer(s) in the text box, display "Please input a computer name" dialog box (I've tried a few ways but can't seem to find a solution that works with the other mentioned above)
3. If there are any errors that come up along the way, skip those computers with errors, and display a list of the specific computer names at the end in dialog box or separate list within the form. (eg. "File transfer complete, the following computers ran into errors: ...")
4. If there were no errors, display the "File transfer completed" dialog box. (Currently in script)

Here is the code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "File Transfer"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(410, 360)
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
$form.MaximizeBox = $false

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380, 20)
$label.Text = "Paste the computer names below:"
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$textbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 40)
$textbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380, 180)
$textbox.Multiline = $true
$form.Controls.Add($textbox)

$fileLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$fileLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 230)
$fileLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380, 20)
$fileLabel.Text = "Selected File: None"
$form.Controls.Add($fileLabel)

$progressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$progressBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 260)
$progressBar.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380, 20)
$form.Controls.Add($progressBar)

$fileButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$fileButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 290)
$fileButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$fileButton.Text = "Select File"
$fileButton.Add_Click({
    $fileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $fileDialog.Title = "Select File to Transfer"
    $result = $fileDialog.ShowDialog()

    if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        $global:selectedFile = $fileDialog.FileName
        $fileLabel.Text = "Selected File: $global:selectedFile"
    }
})
$form.Controls.Add($fileButton)

$transferButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$transferButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150, 290)
$transferButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$transferButton.Text = "Transfer"
$transferButton.Add_Click({
    $computers = $textbox.Text -split "`r`n"

    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($global:selectedFile)) {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please select a file to transfer.", "File Not Selected", "OK", "Warning")
        return
    }

    $totalComputers = $computers.Count
    $progress = 0

    foreach ($computer in $computers) {
        $scriptBlock = {
            param($filePath)

            $destinationPath = "C:\Temp\"
            Copy-Item -Path $filePath -Destination $destinationPath
        }

        $job = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList $global:selectedFile -AsJob

        $progress++
        $progressPercent = [Math]::Round(($progress / $totalComputers) * 100)
        $progressBar.Value = $progressPercent

        while (-not $job.HasMoreData) {
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
        }
    }

    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("File transfer completed.", "Transfer Complete", "OK", "Information")
    $progressBar.Value = 0
})
$form.Controls.Add($transferButton)

$form.ShowDialog()
```